# Retrieve secret value from openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I created a key/value secret in openshift. I want to retrieve the value of that key/value pair.

i tried using

```
oc describe secret ashish -n my-project
```

but it gave the value as shown below but i dont the value for my key it just shows 7bytes.

```
Name:         ashish
Namespace:    my-project
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
ashish:  7 bytes
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get key and value using "oc get secret/SECRETNAME -o yaml" simply, but you should decode the value by base64.
After you retrieve the key using "oc get -o yaml", the value can decode simply as follows.

```
oc get secret ashish -n my-project \
   -o go-template --template="{{.data.KEY|base64decode}}"
VALUE
```

For example,

```
oc get secret ashish -n my-project \
   -o go-template --template="{{.data.ashish|base64decode}}"
...value...
```

Answer (score 4):

As noticed in other comments, Openshift JSONPath rendering (quite rightly) will not handle `@` and `.` in key names. this is also mentioned in OCP domentation on [Using Templates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/using-templates.html#templates-writing-object-list_using-templates)

There are two practical ways around this:

1. Use jsonpath output:

```
oc get secret mysecret -n myproject -o jsonpath="{.data['tls\.key']}" | base64 -d
```

2. Output the files into your current working directory:

```
oc extract secrets/mysecret -n myproject
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `oc get secrets/ashish -o yaml` or `-o json` where you'll see the base64-encoded value. You can then copy the value and decode it with something like echo `<ENCODED_VALUE> | base64 -d`

You can get the decode secret value, single oc command.

```
oc get secret ashish -n my-project --template={{.data.ashish}} | base64 -d
```

Comment: This does not work if your key name contains a `.` character. Which is indeed likely for Secrets mapped as a volume.  (the key becomes a file name)